# ¿Cómo remover archivos de GIT sin borrarlos del disco?

Tags: git, composer

Actualmente hay un sitio en Magento2 y usamos GIT, el problema es que no se ignoraron los archivos de vendor y de cache de la aplicación y para trabajar con Git nos muestra cientos de cambios cuando refrescamos la caché.

Usamos el comando `git rm -r --cached .` después de incluir estas carpetas en el `.gitignore` para eliminarlas sólo del seguimiento de GIT y no del disco duro pero el problema es que al hacer un `git pull` en uno de los servidores donde se prueba la aplicación se borran todos los archivos que están en el `.gitignore`, lo que nos obliga a usar el comando `composer install` y a crear manualmente el archivo de conexión y configuración `env.php` que se encuentra ingnorado.

¿Hay alguna opción para ignorar estos archivos `committed` sin borrarlos en los otros ambientes cuando se hace pull?

Comment: Es tan sencillo como que estas borrando todo el contenido del directorio actual, no debes agregar el punto al final del comando `git rm`, más bien agrega las rutas que agregaste al `.gitignore`.

Comment: no vas a tener problema el composer install solo lo vas a hacer la primera vez y cuando tenga cambios tu environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque en tu copia local hagas `git rm -r --cached env.php` para conservar el archivo en el disco, cuando haces commit del cambio que acaba de ocurrir ese commit lleva la instrucción de borrar el archivo.

```
echo -e "\nenv.php" >> .gitignore
git rm --cached env.php
git status
```

Te dirá:

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    env.php

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   .gitignore
```

No hay manera de hacer esto automáticamente. Cada uno de los que tengan acceso al proyecto tendría que ser instruido para que en vez de hacer

```
git pull origin master
```

(que implica un merge automático y por tanto la eliminación de `env.php`)

Hiciera:

```
git fetch origin
git reset origin/master
git checkout .gitignore
```

Y con eso preservaría el archivo `env.php` y por extensión todos los que producto del cambio en .gitignore hayan salido del control de versiones.